# The setOnTouchListener and the setOnItemClickListener do not work at the same time

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView`. On `ListView`,  I have set two events:

- `setOnTouchListener`
- `setOnItemClickListener`

In my code, the `setOnTouchListener` works but `setOnItemClickListener` does not. When I removed `setOnTouchListener`, `setOnItemClickListener` works fine.

Is there a way for both of them to work at the same time?

Comment: try to return false in `OnTouchListener` implementation

Comment: Would you tell us the purpose of those 2 Listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gunar told you the solution, if you return false on a listener, Android will understand the touch will continue propagating, so the other listerner will be fired.

But maybe you don't need two listener for almost the same action.